# Empty data received in Post Method in WebApi

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi that receive data from my webpage in Post method:
The Api code is:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(PMSCost menu)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (menu.Price != 0)
                         return Ok(1);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```

And Model class Code is :

```
 public class PMSCost
    {
        public string CostName = "";
        public int Price = 0;
    }
```

I call the WebAPi with code:

```
var datatosend = new Object();
datatosend.CostName = "Foooooo";
datatosend.Price = 100;

jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/PMSCost/",
    type: "Post",
    data: datatosend,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "Success") {
            alert("Success");
        }
    },
});
```

The Api called successfully but the `PMSCost` variable (menu) that I post to Api is always have empty value, Something like  `CostName= ""` and `Price= 0` .

Does anyone know whats wring in my code? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you decorate your action with the HttpPost attribute? You also may want to share how the request (using e.g. Fiddler) is sent back to the server.

Comment: no i dont decorate  the action... i think that WebAPI know the action by the name of method, is it my wrong?

Comment: That's one part of the equation, the second one is the verb. So add [HttpPost] to the action and see what happens.

Comment: About *how the request*...I just Run my web site in Visual studio and set breakpoint in Post and trace code....

Comment: @hbulens I added [HttpPost] but still get empty value...I think the webapi code is ok but something is buggy in ajax call of the post method

Comment: That's what I meant with sharing the request data. Tools like Fiddler will show you what's being sent back to the server. You also may want to use a different approach to declare the datatosend variable. { Costname: "Foo", Price: 100 } is fine, no need to instantiate Object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162758/discussion-between-hbulens-and-combo-ci).

Comment: Set the contentType of the request in the ajax call to application/json - I think the default is form-url-encoded and it should still work, but I always customize that so not sure. Also the network tab in the browser dev tools is usually enough and you don't need fiddler to see basic request information, but it will show you how the data is actually sent by jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are posting data to the action, you must add the `[HttpPost]` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(PMSCost menu)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (menu.Price != 0)
                 return Ok(1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

And the AJAX request goes as follows;

```
var dataToSend = {
   CostName: "Foo",
   Price: 100         
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/PMSCost/",
    type: "POST",
    async:true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "Success") {
            alert("Success");
        }
    }
});
```